# Allow Moment.js dates in bootstrap-ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use [Bootstrap UI's](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) [DatePicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) with [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) dates.

It is possible if I convert my model value from Moment.js date to standard `Date` prior to assigning it to a scope:

```js
$scope.myDate = moment('2014-11-07T21:20:15').toDate();
```

However, I would like it to be as transparent as possible, i.e. without the need for manual prior conversion.

I've tried to add wrapping formatters and parsers via directive extension, but it's not working as I'm expecting:

```js
angular
    .module('DatepickerWorkaround', [])
    .directive('datepickerPopup', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EAC',
            require: 'ngModel',
            priority: -10,
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                // Remove the default formatter from the input directive to prevent conflict.
                // This is required for compatibility with AngularJS 1.3.x.
                ngModel.$formatters.shift();

                // Casting Moment.js date to standard date.
                ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function(momentDate) {
                    if (moment.isMoment(momentDate)) {
                        return momentDate.toDate();
                    }
                });

                // Casting standard date back to Moment.js date.
                ngModel.$parsers.push(function(date) {
                    if (date instanceof Date) {
                        return moment(date);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
;
```

With this extension date is displayed correctly in the input field, but when popup opens the incorrect date is selected inside of it.

Also, I'm not quite sure what value should I use for directive `priority` property and what methods should I call on `$formatters` and `$parsers`, i.e. `push()` vs `unshift()`.

Is there a way to make Bootstrap UI's DatePicker work with Moment.js dates transparently?

Answer (score 11):

Decorating the original `datepickerPopup` and `datepicker` directives it's possible to achieve this conversion.

In this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sdOw6EhAKRfnUptsX1mk?p=preview) I've changed the following methods:

- `ngModel.$render` on **datepickerPopup**;
- `parseDate` on **datepickerPopup**;
- *minDate* and *maxDate* `$watch`es on **datepicker**;
- `this.render` on **datepicker**;
- `this.refreshView` on **datepicker**;
- `this.createDateObject` on **datepicker**;
- `$scope.select` on **datepicker**;

with moment.utc() and I'm pretty satisfied with the results. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but you might be able to do this.

Create a customer filter that that returns the normal date...something like the below

```
angular.module('phonecatFilters', []).filter('momentToDate', function() {
    return function(momentDate) {
        if (moment.isMoment(momentDate)) {
            return momentDate.toDate();
        }else { return momentDate }
    };
});
```

Then where you declare you directive 
`ng-model="yourmomentdate | momentToDate"`

Comment: Thank you for the good idea, it could be a valid workaround. I will try to test this approach in the future.

Comment: You cannot have a filter on an ng-mode